# Yielding inside a block

Tags: ruby

I've been given this class which includes the Enumerable module:

```
class Team 
  include Enumerable # LOTS of functionality

  attr_accessor :name, :players 
  def initialize (name) 
    @name = name 
    @players = [] 
  end 
  def add_players (*players) # splat 
    @players += players
  end 
  def to_s 
    "#{@name} team: #{@players.join(", ")}" 
  end 
  def each 
    @players.each { |player| yield player }
  end 
end
```

I know that *yield* is used to be able to call a block inside a method when a block is passed as a method argument. What then does the yield do inside this block?

Comment: It... yields the player. To the block you give `each`. Just like you said. Which would have been pretty easy to test empirically, no?

Comment: @Dave what's the difference between yield and return in this case? Yeah I know I've tested it. What I'm trying to clarify is why *yield* is used, since it's the first time I've seen yield used in such a way.

Comment: Because you don't want to return, you want to yield. They're radically different things.

Comment: As an aside I recommend using `@players.concat` instead of `@players +=`.  The latter creates a new Array instance, while the former does not -- so you're doing less work at runtime.

Comment: Also note that `each` conventionally returns the receiver or an enumerator if no block is given.

Comment: it does the same as next code
`def each(&block);
  @players.each(&block);
end`

Comment: @ArtemBiserov almost, `yield` requires a block, whereas `&block` does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proper functioning of the included `Enumerable` interface's methods requires that the class implement an `each` method that yields successive values.  The implementation in your sample code effectively delegates this logic to that of `Array`'s each method (since `@players` is an Array).

Replacing `yield` with `return` would result in *no* values being provided, and bypassing any code block that was passed in.

You could experiment with the `each` implementation to verify this.

Comment: "Proper function of the included enumerable interface's method requires that the class implement an each method that yields successive values." This did it for me. Thanks!